# Animation problems with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/tKL8E/13/)**.

Relevant code (also annotated in fiddle):

```
// tooltip positioning on hover and overlay fade on all li's except for submenu items that are not the last child
$("ul:not(.sub-menu) > li, ul.sub-menu > li:last-child").not(":has(ul.sub-menu)").hover(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
    title = $(this).children("a").data("title"),
    posL = $this.offset().left + ($this.width() / 2),
    posT = $this.height(),
    tooltip = $("#tooltip"),
    overlay = $("#overlay");

  $this.addClass("over-down");
  overlay.stop(true).fadeIn("slow"); // RELEVANT FOR QUESTION
  tooltip.stop(true, true).text(title).animate({ // RELEVANT FOR QUESTION
    "left": posL - (tooltip.width() / 2),
      "top": posT + $this.offset().top + 20
  }, 300).fadeIn("fast");
}, function () {
  var $this = $(this),
    tooltip = $("#tooltip"),
    overlay = $("#overlay");

  $this.removeClass("over-down");
  overlay.stop(true).fadeOut("slow"); // RELEVANT FOR QUESTION
  tooltip.stop(true).fadeOut(400); // RELEVANT FOR QUESTION
});
```

In the fiddle, try hovering over an item, then briefly leaving it and hovering another item. You will see that the `#overlay` div has partially faded out, as has the `#tooltip` span. What I want is a smooth transition between the two, so normally, tooltip and overlay should fadeIn again to a 100%, but they don't. I have been messing around with that `.stop()` but nothing seems to work.

This problem occurs on every browser tested (IE10, FF, Chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `.stop(true)` in the middle of a `fadeOut`, the item will not be set to `display:none` hence the next `fadeIn` will have no effect.

There are 2 possible solutions:

Using `.stop(true, true)` before the `fadeIn` will force an abrupt `display:none` on the element and hence enable a `fadeIn` in succession. This is not a very smoothly solution. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/15/)

Another solution is to use [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) instead of `fadeIn`. `fadeTo` will animate the opacity similar to `fadeIn`, but without the `display:none` requirement. It also works on hidden elements fading them in as `fadeIn` does:

```
$this.addClass("over-down");
overlay.stop(true).fadeTo(600, .75); //edited here
tooltip.stop(true, true).text(title).animate({ //here*
    "left": posL - (tooltip.width() / 2),
    "top": posT + $this.offset().top + 20
}, 300).fadeTo(200, 1); //and here
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/14/)

This is a way more smoothly solution. It will animate the element properly back to `.75` opacity independently of its current opacity or display.

*Added a `.stop(true, true)` to the tooltip so it doesn't stay half-faded while your `fadeTo` is queued. If you want to slide such them, try:

```
var do_dequeue = tooltip.is(':visible');
tooltip.stop(true).text(title).animate({ // RELEVANT FOR QUESTION
    "left": posL - (tooltip.width() / 2),
    "top": posT + $this.offset().top + 20,
}, 300).fadeTo(200, 1);
if (do_dequeue) tooltip.dequeue();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/19/)

The `do_dequeue` var keeps track of whether the tooltip was partially faded before preparing the move then fade queue, if it is partially faded then it won't wait for the tooltip to be placed under the element before fading it back to full opacity. I guess this is the smoother it can get. `=]`

Comment: Thank you for your effort! (+1) The point of the `animate`, however, was that the tooltip would slide from on link to another. This effect is gone now. If it is not possible to implement this, I can leave it out. But it would be cool though! :)

Comment: If the partially faded-in tooltip is a problem, I can fix that by conditionally using a different animation queue. That will obviously take a little more code though.

Comment: @BramVanroy Here's my final version for now http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/19/ experiment a bit with partially faded tooltips and hidden ones, if that isn't what you had in mind, comment and I'll update it. `=]`

Comment: Wow, that's great! Really a great solution! I wish I could give you more than +1! Thanks again!